# jquery find next class in a list

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know this question has been asked a few times but none of the answers seem to work, or at least that I have found anyway.

I need to select the error class from the list items after checking input from the form input.

Here is what I have:

The html:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
    <li class="input"><input name="fname" type="text" /></li>
    <li class="icon"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="error"></li>

    <li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
    <li class="input"><input name="lname" type="text" /></li>
    <li class="icon"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="error"></li>

    <li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
    <li class="input"><input name="uname" type="text" /></li>
    <li class="icon"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="error"></li>

    <li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
    <li class="input"><input name="password" type="password" /></li>
    <li class="icon"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="error"></li>
 </ul>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('input[name=uname]').on("input", function() {

var input = $.trim(this.value);
var BLIDRegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

if(input == 0){
    uname_status = false;
    $(this).closest('li').next('.icon').html('<img src="/assets/images/png/glyphicons_199_ban.png" />');
    $(this).parent('li').next().next().next('li').show(); 
    $(this).parent('li').next().next().next('li').html('<span>You must enter a Username!</span>');
    return false;
}
});
```

The above **does work**, I was just wondering if there is a better way of selecting the "error" class than using:

```
    $(this).parent('li').next().next().next('li').show();
```

I have tried the following and they didn't work:

```
// From another stackoverflow question
$(this).closest('li').nextAll(':has(.error):first').find('.error');

$(this).parents('li').eq(0).next().find('li.error');

// Works but selects the next error class' and the one after
$(this).closest('li').nextAll('li.error').show();  
or
$(this).parent('li').nextAll('li.error').show();
```

Is there another solution? Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and filter the results to get [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/), as:

```
$('input[name=uname]').on("input", function() {
    ......
    $(this).parents(".input")
        .nextAll(".error").first().html('<span>You must enter a Username!</span>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

1) How rigid is this structure? You will have much better control and luck if you group the form fields:

```
<ul class="form-field">
 <li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
 <li class="input"><input name="fname" type="text" /></li>
 <li class="icon"></li>
 <li class="clearfix"></li>
 <li class="error"></li>
</ul>
```

Or something more like Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="Input1">Lable</label>
 <input name="fname" type="text" class="form-control" id="Input1"/><i class="icon"></i>
 <div class="error"></div>
</div>
```

With either, the parent of any item will only include the relevant siblings.

2) If you don't have the freedom for direct changes, try dynamically grouping the elements with a unique class name: http://jsfiddle.net/2Kquq/4/ (updated with click actions)

3) The clearfix li seems like needless code.  You can get the clear by

- grouping elements in a parent (like #1 above) or
- adding the clearfix to an existing < li/> or
- adding display:block to your error and/or icon.

4) If you have to stay with this markup only, you can try nextUntil(".error").next() to select the next error div.

Comment: I can change the mark-up, im not the best with css however I am using the twitter bootstrap. My form has 2 columns with labels to the left and inputs to the right then a icon appearing to the right of the input and the error displaying below the input. I do like the idea of grouping the fields however for now I am going to go with what I have. I may on the future try using your method as it seems fairly elegant and much cleaner. For now I have accepted sudhir answer as it took care of what I was needing for now. Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?  Given either version, you are reinventing the wheel a bit on this project - Bootstrap has many answers built right in.

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.2. Wow! If only I knew that sooner. Those form fields look much cleaner! That's ok gives me something to do over the weekend right? lol!

Answer (score 0):

`.nextAll()` is probably what you wanted

```
$('input[name=uname]').on("input", function() {

var input = $.trim(this.value);
var BLIDRegExpression = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

if(input == 0){
    uname_status = false;
    $(this).parent('li').next('.icon').html('<img src="/assets/images/png/glyphicons_199_ban.png" />');
    var $nextError = $(this).parent('li').nextAll('error:first');
    $nextError.html('<span>You must enter a Username!</span>'); 
    $nextError.show();
    return false;
}
});
```

I'm curious as to why you don't just have them in separate `ul`s though which would make the selectors simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the markup you could group your li-groups in seperate lists like so:

```
<ul>
<li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
<li class="input"><input name="fname" type="text" /></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="clearfix"></li>
<li class="error"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
<li class="input"><input name="lname" type="text" /></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="clearfix"></li>
<li class="error"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
<li class="input"><input name="uname" type="text" /></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="clearfix"></li>
<li class="error"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="label"><label>Label</label></li>
<li class="input"><input name="password" type="password" /></li>
<li class="icon"></li>
<li class="clearfix"></li>
<li class="error"></li>
</ul>
```

Then you could simply go for

```
$(this).parent('ul').find('.error').show();
```